# Map the values of a object to the values of another object

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON array

```
    {
     "data": [
        {
        "id": 659,
        "source_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-01-13T06:35:08.000000Z",
        "products": [
            {
                "name": "532",
                "properties": [
                    {
                        "name": "color",
                        "value": "blue"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "size",
                        "value": "1"
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 658,
        "source_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2023-01-12T21:36:06.000000Z",
        "products": [
            {
                "name": "532",
                "properties": [
                    {
                        "name": "color",
                        "value": "khaki"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "size",
                        "value": "2"
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    },
    ],
    }
```

All code I have so far:

```
   var rows = [], sortOrder = ['fabric', 'color', 'size'], orderSource = [{"Insta" : 1, "Retail" : 2}];

   dataSet.forEach((e) => {
       e.products.forEach((product) => {
           product.properties = product.properties.sort((a, b) => {
               return sortOrder.indexOf(a.name) - sortOrder.indexOf(b.name);
       });

       product.properties = sortOrder.map((i => name => product.properties[i].name === name ?
           product.properties[i++] : {name, value : ''})(0));

       rows.push([e.id, e.source_id, new Date(e.created_at).toLocaleDateString('uk-UK'),      
           product.name].concat(product.properties.map(p => p.value)).concat([product.quantity, 
           product.comment]));
  
       console.log(rows);
       });
    });
```

Console output looks like this

```
    [ 659, 1, '13.01.2023', '532', 'blue', '1' ],
    [ 658, 2, '12.01.2023', '532', 'khaki', '2' ]
```

I need the data from the array `orderSource = [{"Insta" : 1, "Retail" : 2}]` to be reassigned to the resulting array so that it looks like this

```
    [ 659, 'Insta', '13.01.2023', '532', 'blue', '1' ],
    [ 658, 'Retail', '12.01.2023', '532', 'khaki', '2' ]
```

This is necessary in order to then write the array to the Google spreadsheet
I am new to programming, so I do not consider it necessary to list here all my attempts to reassign values in the resulting array))
Any of your help is welcome

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. Please validate and fix your data. You can use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use the array method `Array.find()` on the object's keys to find the relevant key (e.g. Insta, Retail).

```js
const rows = [],
  sortOrder = ['fabric', 'color', 'size'],
  orderSource = [{
    "Insta": 1,
    "Retail": 2
  }];

dataSet.forEach((e) => {
  e.products.forEach((product) => {
    product.properties = product.properties.sort((a, b) => {
      return sortOrder.indexOf(a.name) - sortOrder.indexOf(b.name);
    });

    product.properties = sortOrder.map((i => name => product.properties[i].name === name ?
      product.properties[i++] : {
        name,
        value: ''
      })(0));

    // Use the Array.find() method on the object's keys
    const key = Object.keys(orderSource[0]).find(key => orderSource[0][key] === e.source_id);

    rows.push([e.id, key, new Date(e.created_at).toLocaleDateString('uk-UK'),
      product.name
    ].concat(product.properties.map(p => p.value)).concat([product.quantity,
      product.comment
    ]));

  });
});

console.log(rows);
```